# smoother scrolling using scrollbar and mouse wheel

Tags: javascript, scroll, scrollbar

I am trying to do a smoother scrolling on my single webpage. It is easy to do it when I click on a link or button, but I don't know how to do it when I use the mouse wheel or the scrollbar. I've seen this in many pages. Next there is an example of what I am talking about:
http://icscreative.com/

I hope being clear enough.

Do you have some clue of how to do it?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/victa/curtain.js is a great library that accomplishes a similar effect

Comment: I've just checked the library, but is not what I'm looking for. It is very useful of course, but I am looking for a smooth scroll. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something that decelerates the scrolling after flicking the scroll wheel?

If you are check this one out: http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/

The site itself is an example.